# Android Picasso Dropbox: How to load images into gridview

Tags: android, dropbox, picasso

1. I'm using Dropbox Android SDK for getting photos and show it into a GridView.
2. Currently, I'm using Picasso for adapter with another images resources like GPhotos, Facebook... too.
3. How can I get downloadable link from Dropbox's file? Or How to use Picasso load Dropbox's image?
   This is the way I get the Dropbox image:

   ```java
   List<Entry> listEntry = mApi.search("/photos", ".jpg", 0, false);

   int i = 0;
   for (Entry entry : listEntry) {
       if (this.isRemoving()) { // Check if fragment is being removed
           return;
       }
       if (!entry.isDir) { // Check if this entry is dir or file
           i++;
           Log.e(TAG, entry + " --- " + entry.fileName() + " --- "
                   + entry.parentPath() + " --- " + entry.modified);
           final DropboxLink shareLink = mApi.share(entry.parentPath()
                   + entry.fileName());
           url = shareLink.url;
           Log.v(TAG, "shareLink: " + shareLink.url);
           // The file name I get is ImageName.JPG and path is /Photos
           // With share() the url I get looks like https://db.tt/xxxxxxxx
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer insight about using Picasso, but if you can accept the file data directly, using [`getFile`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) or [`getThumbnail`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.ThumbSize,%20com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.ThumbFormat,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) instead of [`share`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#share(java.lang.String)) would be better.

If you do need a URL that Picasso can directly download from, you should use the [`media`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#media(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) method instead.

Comment: tks for your reply, i read about Dropbox API but with current i only think the flow for getting an image from Dropbox and showing on Adapter is:
1. Search images in Photos folder (1 request)<br/>
2. Using [media][1] for getting direct URL (1 * (images) requests)<br/>
3. Using Picasso in adapter (1 * (images) requests)<br/>
I will have count(images) * 2 + 1 requests count, so terrible
So, need a better solution @@
<br/>
WHY CAN I USE LINE BREAK OR REF LINK PLS???

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Greg for suggestion, i have a little notice for using Picasso with Dropbox SDK.

When use [media](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#media(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) i have to use option TRUE in SSL for success loading image from Picasso, if FALSE Picasso cannot load links.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample from dropbox about this, try to check this link [dropbox sample](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android)

there is 2 files that you need to see **PicassoClient**.java And **FileThumbnailRequestHandler**.java

here's the code :

PicassoClient Class :

```
public class PicassoClient {
    private static Picasso sPicasso;

    public static void init(Context context, DbxClientV2 dbxClient) {

        // Configure picasso to know about special thumbnail requests
        sPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(context))
                .addRequestHandler(new FileThumbnailRequestHandler(dbxClient))
                .build();
    }


    public static Picasso getPicasso() {
        return sPicasso;
    }
}
```

FileThumbnailRequestHandler class :

```
public class FileThumbnailRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {

    private static final String SCHEME =  "dropbox";
    private static final String HOST = "dropbox";
    private final DbxClientV2 mDbxClient;

    public FileThumbnailRequestHandler(DbxClientV2 dbxClient) {
        mDbxClient = dbxClient;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a {@link Uri} for a Dropbox file thumbnail suitable for handling by this handler
     */
    public static Uri buildPicassoUri(FileMetadata file) {
        return new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(SCHEME)
                .authority(HOST)
                .path(file.getPathLower()).build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHandleRequest(Request data) {
        return SCHEME.equals(data.uri.getScheme()) && HOST.equals(data.uri.getHost());
    }

    @Override
    public Result load(Request request, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {

        try {
            DbxDownloader<FileMetadata> downloader =
                    mDbxClient.files().getThumbnailBuilder(request.uri.getPath())
                            .withFormat(ThumbnailFormat.JPEG)
                            .withSize(ThumbnailSize.W1024H768)
                            .start();

            return new Result(downloader.getInputStream(), Picasso.LoadedFrom.NETWORK);
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to import those 2 classes that i mentioned above then get the sPicasso object then you're ready to use it . :)

Comment: How can i run the example?